# Unresolved external symbol for imp_fputws, imp_towupper in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, linker

I am developing windows program, and got link error :

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wcsicmp
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fputws
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_towupper
```

It seems like I need wide char version fputs() and toupper(), but I can't find it.

Could someone provide the library name or compile settings that will resolve the link error?

Environment : Win server 2008 + visual studio 2010 pro + WinDDK 7600.16385.1

Comment: These are standard exports provided by vc/lib/msvcrt.lib.  The library that automatically gets linked when you compile with /MD, the default.  Very hard to guess what you might have done to prevent that from happening, do not use /MT.

Comment: Can you paste the compiler and linker command lines you used?  (Available via the project properties)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was the case for you, but I was using the (lib file) meant for a MD runtime execution instead of a MT runtime execution. 
Using the correct lib in:
Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies 
helped me fix the issue